# Как правильно сделать пост запрос?

Tags: c#, httpclient

пытаюсь создать короткую ссылку с помощью сервиса bit.ly
Я сделал вот такой код, но почему то ничего не происходит.
Документация: https://dev.bitly.com/

```
class Program
{
    static HttpClient httpClient;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
        CreateLink();
    }
    async static void CreateLink()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "");

        var stringContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("group_guid", ""),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("domain", "bit.ly"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("long_url", "https://google.com"),
        });
        var respone = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten", stringContent);
        Console.WriteLine(respone);
    }
}
```

Comment: `{ "group_guid": "Ba1bc23dE4F", ... }` - это JSON (там даже можно найти [это](https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference#createBitlink), где увидите `Content-Type: application/json`).

Comment: нет не удалось .